# using for each loop to show three Dimentional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Here is my 3 dimensional array. I want to show my array for profession like Designer,Developer,Engineer. That means end of the last element of my profession it will implode full stop rather than comma. In my code it can implode comma. How can I check the last element of that array? I used end function but it doesn't work.

```
$friends=[
    "John"=>[
        'Location'=>'Dhaka', 
        'Age'=>30, 
        'Profession'=>['Designer','Developer','Engineer']
    ],
    "Bill"=>[
        'Location'=>'CTG',
        'Age'=>29,
        'Profession'=>['Programmer','Engineer','Teacher']
    ],
    "Mark"=>[
         'Location'=>'Barishal',
         'Age'=>33,
         'Profession'=>['Network','Hardware','Engineer']
    ]
];

foreach ($friends as $Name=> $value) {
    echo "Name : $Name </br>";  
    foreach ($value as $info => $info_value) {
       if (is_array($info_value)) {
         echo $info.":";
         foreach ($info_value as $key=>$profession) {
            echo $profession.",";
         }
       }else{
         echo "{$info}:{$info_value}</br>";
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Give some example output of how you want the output to look. Otherwise poeple will most likley missinterpred you ;)

Comment: i explained it top of the portion as well as output demo

Comment: I saw no formatted example output. It also shows in answers that people had different ideas about what you wanted. So next time show something, like the sample output from Ceeee for example, and people will have a clear ideas of the exact layout you are looking for,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach ($friends as $Name => $value) {
    echo "Name : $Name </br>";  
    foreach ($value as $info => $info_value) {
        if (is_array($info_value)) 
            echo "$info : ". implode(', ', $info_value) . '.</br>';
        else
            echo "$info : $info_value </br>";
    }
    echo '</br>';
}
```

sample output would be:

```
Name : John 
Location : Dhaka 
Age : 30 
Profession : Designer, Developer, Engineer.

Name : Bill 
Location : CTG 
Age : 29 
Profession : Programmer, Engineer, Teacher.

Name : Mark 
Location : Barishal 
Age : 33 
Profession : Network, Hardware, Engineer.
```

Comment: Your code doesn't fulfill my requirement.i said end of the element it will implode comma.but concatenate a dot end of the element it fulfills my requirement.like echo "$info : ". implode(', ',$info_value)."." . '</br>';       btw thnx :)

Comment: because of a dot my answer didn't solved your question :( too bad for me

Comment: @hmamun accept if this answers your question :) thanks

Comment: it's okay :)it really appreciable

Answer (score 0):

```
output:

Name : John 
Location:Dhaka
Age:30
Profession:Designer,Developer,Engineer

Name : Bill 
Location:CTG
Age:29
Profession:Programmer,Engineer,Teacher

Name : Mark 
Location:Barishal
Age:33
Profession:Network,Hardware,Engineer
```

If you want these output please consider this code below

```
<?php
foreach ($friends as $Name => $value) {
    echo "Name : $Name </br>";
    foreach ($value as $info => $info_value) {
        if (is_array($info_value)) {
            echo $info . ":";
            $profession_arr = array();
            foreach ($info_value as $key => $profession) {
                $profession_arr[] = $profession;
            }
            $prof_str = implode(",", $profession_arr);
            echo $prof_str . "</br>";
        } else {
            echo "{$info}:{$info_value}</br>";
        }
    }
    echo "</br>";
}
```

otherwise explain how you want.